# Загрузка базы в программу онлайн

Tags: xampp

Здравствуйте! Возник очередной вопрос к вам. Я работаю в компании, которая написала программу, в этой программе есть база данных, которую мы пополняем. Так вот, программа работает в онлайне, но для того, чтоб выставить базу онлайн, я загружаю сначала базу в оффлайн, а затем переношу через localhost/phpmyadmin.... в онлайн программу. Вопрос: как можно сразу загружать в онлайн? Большое спасибо!

Comment: ХэшКод вы не уснули)))))

Answer (score 1):

В скрипте подключаемся к БД, формируем запрос на вставку-обновление - отсылаем) - вот в принципе и все. Если программа самописная, то труда сделать это не составит, я думаю.
А чтоб конкретно написать вам скрип (помочь), нужна структура БД и структра источника данных для загрузки.

Comment: Честно говоря, я надеялся услышать ответ попроще, так как вообще не особо разбираюсь в программировании. Короче говоря, я мало что понял из ваших ответов. Постараюсь по подробней описать процесс загрузки в базу и, пожалуйста, ответьте как можно проще. В первую очередь я загружаю необходимую информацию в базу, затем захожу в `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` вкладка импорт и уже с MySQL выгружаю в онлайн. Можно ли теперь напрямую качать в онлайн?

Comment: В первую очередь я загружаю необходимую информацию в базу, затем захожу в `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` - назовем загрузка в `базу1`.
Каким образом (с помощью чего) вы загружаете необходимую информацию в `базу1`?

Comment: С помощью той самой программы, которую написала моя организация. БД хранится в MySQL и оттуда переношу ее в онлайн.

Comment: Попросить ваших программистов исправить программу (а имено строку подключения сделать на базу онлайн). Или есть какой то особый смысл в базе оффлайн?

Comment: Ale_x можешь с этим по подробнее, где именно ее изменить? и можно ли будет при таком варианте загружать и в оффлайн одновременно?

Answer (score -1):

А кто мешает Вашей программе сразу подключатся к онлайн базе? Ну разве только то, что mysql, где лежит база, не разрешает подключений через не локалхост. (Проверить в файле `my.ini` строку  `bind-address=127.0.0.1` (прописать свой внешний айпи или закоментировать), также проверить фаервол).